# accessing form variables from class in dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, interface

I have a dll that has an interface class and a form.

```
public class Main : M.ModuleInterface
{
    void M.ModuleInterface.showForm()
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

    List<byte> M.ModuleInterface.ReadAll()
    {
        List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

The problem is I have a textbox that I want to read the value from dll's form and to be able to access/pass it from ReadAll() method and set access controls from interface class if possible. How can I accomplish this? I created public static class with public static members on Form1.cs, but I can't access it using frm.MyStaticClass. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that there's a textbox on `Form1` that you want to be able to access in `ReadAll`?

Comment: @DStanley that's correct, and other way around if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnot provide enough info for a personal answer. But here is how I'd access a form from a dll. Let's say we have a class withing a dll file that looks as follows:

```
namespace smth
{
    public partial class mytest : Form
    {
        public TextBox txt;

        public mytest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Then we would load the form to our project like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:\\mydllfile.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetType("smth.mytest");
Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Now you can access the form.txt.
Hope this helps.